# How to alias a column with identifier that contains spaces?

Tags: sql, hive

Does anyone know the syntax for aliasing a column without underscores in Hive?  In SQL and MYSQL you can use single quotes or brackets.  This does not seem to work in Hive.  Here a simple query that wouldn't work:

```
select inbound_handled as 'IB Handled' 
from shdev.cust_data
```

Comment: Please avoid descriptions such as "does not seem to work" and instead describe the behavior you expierience (e.g. "The CLI is being aborted" / "The computer is on fire"), in this case I assume you are getting an error message, so please add it.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax is:

```
select inbound_handled as `IB Handled` 
from shdev.cust_data
```

In Hive release 0.12.0 and earlier, column names can only contain alphanumeric and underscore characters.

In Hive release 0.13.0 and later, by default column names can be specified within backticks (`) and contain any Unicode character (HIVE-6013). Within a string delimited by backticks, all characters are treated literally except that double backticks (``) represent one backtick character. The pre-0.13.0 behavior can be used by setting `hive.support.quoted.identifiers` to `none`, in which case backticked names are interpreted as regular expressions. See Supporting Quoted Identifiers in Column Names for details.

See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterColumn

Comment: The OP doesn't really want to "rename" a column, just to alias it :-)